"paired" comparison of more than two algorithms
When comparing two algorithms $A$ and $B$ on test data $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ by means of a performance measure that yields $A(x_i)$ and $B(x_i)$, there are two standard methods:

Check whether $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n A(x_i)-B(x_i) > 0$ and assert statistical significance with a paired t-test.
Check whether $A(x_i)>B(x_i)$ in more than $n/2$ cases and assert statistical significance with a sign test.

In both cases, the test statistic is also a measurement of effect size.
How is this generalized to more than two algorithms? For the second method, I can think of the following procedure:

Determine the ranking of the algorithms for all $x_i$, and compute the average rank for all algorithms. The best algorithm has the highest rank.
To test whether this algorithm is statistically significantly better than all other algorithms, a paired comparison to all other algorithms (by one of the paired methods above) should be significant in all cases.

As this seems to be a standard problem, I wonder what the standard procedure is and how it differs from my suggestion.

There is no single accepted method.  I would go with an empirical approach targeted at estimating the mean absolute discrepancy between two estimates.  This is detailed here where a cluster bootstrap method for getting compatibility (AKA confidence) intervals for the measure is also given.  Briefly you form all possible pairs of values, take the absolute difference, and average that over the pairs and over observations.  This is better than hypothesis testing as it gets to the actual magnitude of the discrepancy, i.e., practical significance, not statistical “significance”.

Thanks for the reference. Actually, I am not interested in statistical signifcance as an indicator of real significance (which it is not), but as a mere safeguard that my sample size was large enough (if it was not, I can increase it). I haven't looked at the details of the reference, but from your description this seems similar to a paired t-test on all pairs of algorithms (which averages the differences, not the absolute differences).

The method I outlined uses unsigned differences so do not allow errors to cancel as does the t-test.
